# Every time im using apt-get or dpkg for installing packages on ubuntu 18 i got those errors from python packages

Tags: django, shell, ubuntu

This problem come from , when i want to host django mysql application to ubuntu 18 with pythonV3.10 and mysqlV5 pip does not install mysqlclient i solve it by upgrade mysql to V8 and minimize python to V3.8 , But I still got error every installation with apt or dpkg even pip . Please help

### Shell Errors

```
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__version__.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/auth.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/certs.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/compat.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/cookies.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/exceptions.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/help.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/hooks.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/packages.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/status_codes.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/structures.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/utils.py'
```

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-requests (--configure):
 installed python3-requests package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 


1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-acme:
 python3-acme depends on python3-requests (>= 2.4.1); however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-acme (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-certbot:
 python3-certbot depends on python3-acme (>= 0.26.0~); however:
  Package python3-acme is not configured yet.
 python3-certbot depends on python3-requests (>= 2.4.3); however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-certbot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-requests-toolbelt:
 python3-requests-toolbelt depends on python3-requests; however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-requests-toolbelt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 firewalld
 python3-wheel
 python3-requests
 python3-acme
 python3-certbot
 python3-requests-toolbelt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1456908

Comment: @rahul.m I try but it still throw same errors thanks